# Calculate the probability of multiple events

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

At work I'm running into a problem with probability calculation which I can't seem to wrap my head around... can someone point me in the direction of the concepts I need to figure out to solve this?

My current approach would be write a program for this and just run a couple of simulations, but this seems like the kind of thing that can be solved mathematically with the primary advantage of being able to plot the results easily.

Problem: Given the following situation...

- Let N be the amount of users participating in a draw
- In a set of possible prizes P, each user can only win one or none. (as soon as you win a prize, you can no longer win the other prizes - your iteration stops (first prize is most valuable, then second prize, etc).
- The prizes are iterated in the same order for all users.
- Each prize has a predefined chance to be won.
- The prize selection algorithm iterates over the prizes in a fixed order.
- Some prizes can be won multiple times (for example, 10 copies of a book can be given away), so after 10 winners for that prize it will be removed from the prize pool.

... calculate for N amount of users the chance of all prize being given away (ie: the system running out of prizes).

As an example, the prizes look like this:

Prize A: 1:100.000 - can be won 1x
Prize B: 1:10.000 - can be won 10x

For my non-mathematically trained way of thinking, these are just too many conditions to effectively model without resorting to actual simulation... but hopefully math.SE can prove me wrong?

Comment: Hi.  Does the algorithm for giving away prizes go one user at a time?  So the first user has a better chance of getting certain prizes than a later user?  Or does it iterate over all the prizes, and for each one it goes through all the remaining users?  Or does it do all the users at once?

Comment: Hi Goos - you're right in that the algo favors users who come before, so yes, earlier users have a (slightly) better chance of winning than the later users.